# How to animate button movement during Fade Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

In code snippet you can see I have 2 buttons when i click on fade out button my paragraph fade out during this fade out I want my buttons to take place of paragraph slowly animatedly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeOut()
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>
```

Comment: is there a specific reason to use Fade? if not using slideUp(), slideDown() should do it by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").css({ opacity: 0, transition: 'opacity 0.5s' }).slideUp(500);

    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("p").css({ opacity: 1, transition: 'opacity 0.5s' }).slideDown(500);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").slideUp(1000);
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    $("p").slideDown(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>
```

Comment: Good answer but the original poster seeks the `fade` effect and this is sliding effect.

Comment: @Inuka yaa, but as per above requirement i think sliding effect is more preferable

Comment: Thank you so much for your response I appreciate on your different way of solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` instead of `fadeIn()/fadeOut()`. That way you will get a smooth animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").slideUp()
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    $("p").slideDown();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>
```

Also, I don't think there is need for two buttons for this operation, and in this case you can just use `slideToggle()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").slideToggle()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
```

Comment: Toggle wasn't my concern, actually I share this code only to explain my question, also my requirement was fade-out but thank you for your quick response. I am shocked to see such quick response :)